# how can I make my interstitial adMob ad show overtime a button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob, interstitial

Right now it only shows the full page ad one time. When I go back and press the button again it does not show. I would like it to show overtime my button is clicked. I have my AdMob hooked up to my Firebase project.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {


var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

@IBAction func loadAd(_ sender: Any) {

    if (interstitial.isReady){
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-11111111/9758796532")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Just do one thing create GADInterstitial request on viewwiiappear()  your problem solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create GAD request every time.

> GADInterstitial is a one time use object. That means once an
>   interstitial is shown, hasBeenUsed returns true and the interstitial
>   can't be used to load another ad. To request another interstitial,
>   you'll need to create a new GADInterstitial object. The best practice,
>   as shown above, is to have a helper method to handle creating and
>   loading an interstitial.

```
 @IBAction func loadAd(_ sender: Any) {
         interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-11111111/9758796532")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)

    }
```

And while loaded successfully you need to present at delegate method

```
optional func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial!){
    if (interstitial.isReady){
           interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
         }
}

optional func interstitialWillDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial!){
      interstitial.delegate = nil
      interstitial = nil
 } 

 optional func interstitialDidFail(toPresentScreen ad: GADInterstitial!){
   interstitial.delegate = nil
   interstitial = nil
  }
```

More : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/interstitial

Answer (score 0):

When dismissing the interstitial we have to **create and make load request** for next interstitial ads.

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
  interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

*The best place to allocate another interstitial is in the interstitialDidDismissScreen: method on GADInterstitialDelegate so that the next interstitial starts loading as soon as the previous one is dismissed. You may even consider breaking out interstitial initialization into its own helper method:*

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/interstitial